# React Native build fails on run-ios

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I've been unable to run my React Native project since Xcode updated to 12.5. I have a feeling the problem is with Flipper, but when I comment out Flipper from my Podfile, I get similar errors for other modules. Here is the error I get with Flipper installed:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/mohammedibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DinDin-cpajpwxpvpxihbgmxeemayoewtno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperRSocketResponder.o /Users/mohammedibrahim/Documents/code/dindin/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperRSocketResponder.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Comment: You may follow this topic: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179

Answer (score 0):

Just update your podfile this way

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['WRAPPER_EXTENSION'] == 'bundle'
        config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = '662Y85Q9D6'
      end

      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.4'

      # **************Just add this line in your Podfile**************
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION']
    end
  end
end
```

Or in your ios\projectname\AppDelegate.m update this code

```
// From this
return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

// To this
return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
```

Probably one of these two solutions, or both will solve your problem

References:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39568

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37748